# all ajax ready event on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm using `$(document).ready` but that will not work for all ajax ready. I need a callback event after all ajax load finished in jquery.

How to write this event using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

ajaxComplete(callback);

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxComplete#callback